# Optimal PCL Template Alignment setup

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, template-matching

I'v got 2 point clouds (in mm unit), one is a "mesh" sampled from stl object (99999 points), and second is point cloud of this object taken by 3D cam (about 30841 points). I am using this PCL tutorial's code for template matching: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/template_alignment.php. After that, I am using PCL ICP code for final alignment. But I am still getting quite bad initial guess from Template Alignment. (eg. no rotation, half-match,...)

I tried change settings from:

```
normal_radius_(0.02f)
feature_radius_(0.02f)
min_sample_distance_(0.05f)
max_correspondence_distance_(0.01f * 0.01f)
nr_iterations_(50)
```

to this one:

```
normal_radius_(2.0f)
feature_radius_(2.0f)
min_sample_distance_(0.5f)
max_correspondence_distance_(1.0f * 1.0f)
nr_iterations_(1000)
```

Can someone please give me some hints how to improve this code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters which are *resolution-dependent* should be also set in relation to the *resolution* of the point cloud.
Paramerets which are *object-size-dependent* should be also set in relation to the size of the object.

Some examples:

- `normal_radius: 4-8 * <resolution>`
  To compute *good* normals, the underlying surface has to have enough points to represent a stable surface. If your units are in `mm`, then you chose a radius of `2mm`, which is way too small.
- `feature_radius: 1-2 * <normal_radius>`
  Same goes for computing *features* as for *normals*.
- `max_correspondence_distance:` You set this value to `1mm*1mm`, which means, that correspondeces can only be `1mm` apart to be categorized as correspondences.  Here it is important to use a value which is in relation to your object's size. You should ask yourself, *"What's the maximum allowed distance between my object and reference such that my object is still a match?"* If you are comparing faces, you should use some `centimeter`s, e.g. `1cm-5cm`, since a face is rather small. But let's say you want to compare big objects like buildings.  There you can use values up to `1m`.
- `min_sample_distance:` Here almost the same applies as for `max_correspondence_distance`. You should ask yourself, *"How much should a sample be distant from another sample?"*. The smaller the value, the more samples you'll get. Again, choose a value which is a fraction of your object's size, but also consider that it shouldn't be smaller than your cloud's resolution. You set it to `0.5mm`, which is way too small.
- `nr_iterations:` Usually not that important, but values between `100-500` are reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

**normal_radius_**:

- Choose according to the density of your cloud (you want it to be large enough to capture *enough* points in the environment - if it's too small the normal will be noisy, up to complete junk or fail to calculate)
- Take into account the smoothness of your cloud (you want it small enough so that it would be correct to approximate the local environment to a plane - if it's too large the normal will be too smooth and ignore small details)

**min_sample_distance_**:

- Mostly computational aspect. The larger the sampling distance, the faster it will work.
- If it's too large, you loose accuracy of the alignment.

**feature_radius_**:

- You need to consider at what scale you have discriminitive structures/shapes
- With faces for example, I've had success with a feature radius of about 1/10th of the model size.

**max_correspondence_distance_**:

- Depends on your starting conditions - how far can 2 corresponding points be. Providing an initial guess using some heuristic can help you reduce this parameter, and improve both performance and results.
- Note that this is the squared-distance

**In your case** (two cloud of the same object), if your cloud has normals, a good initial guess can be achieved without using SampleConsensusInitialAlignment at all. Simply align the mean normal of both clouds. You can apply to following method to both of your clouds to put them in a "normalized" position and orientation:

```
void ToOrigin(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZINormal>::Ptr cloud, Eigen::Affine3f & transformation, Eigen::Vector3f up, float resolution)
{
    // Calc Origin

    pcl::PointXYZINormal origin;
    auto size = cloud->points.size();
    for (auto pointItr = cloud->begin(); pointItr != cloud->end(); pointItr++)
    {
        origin.getArray3fMap() += pointItr->getArray3fMap() / size;
        origin.getNormalVector3fMap() += pointItr->getNormalVector3fMap();
    }
    origin.getNormalVector3fMap().normalize();

    // Calc Transformation  

    auto proj = origin.getNormalVector3fMap().dot(up) * origin.getNormalVector3fMap();

    // the direction that will be rotated to y_axis
    // (the part of "up" that is perpendicular to the cloud normal)
    auto y_direction = (up - proj).normalized();

    // the direction that will be rotated to z_axis
    auto z_direction = origin.getNormalVector3fMap();   

    // the point that will be shifted to origin (0,0,0)
    auto center = origin.getArray3fMap();               

    pcl::getTransformationFromTwoUnitVectorsAndOrigin(y_direction, z_direction, center, transformation);

    // Transform

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZINormal> cloud_tmp;
    pcl::transformPointCloudWithNormals(*cloud, cloud_tmp, transformation);
    pcl::copyPointCloud(cloud_tmp, *cloud);
}
```